# How to get an associative array of rows from a subquery with postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design, subquery

I'm new to postgres and trying out some things before I take the leap over from mySQL.

What I'm trying to do is get an array of associative arrays into a single query.
It has to do with users that can select multiple contact types like phone, email and Facebook and I would like to retrieve those into the column 'contact'.

For a visualisation:

```
{
"first_name": "This",
"last_name": "is me",
"likes": [],
"city": null
```

}

And I would like to get something like this:

```
{
"first_name": "This",
"last_name": "Is me",
"likes": [],
"city": null,
"contact": 
    [
      {"type":1, "value":"myemail@gmail.com", "privacy_rule":1},
      {"type":4, "value":"myfacebook", "privacy_rule":1},
      {"type":9, "value":"mylinkedin", "privacy_rule":1}
    ]
}
```

So the main query would be:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.about, ARRAY(SELECT like_id FROM users_likes l WHERE l.user_id = u.user_id), u.city FROM users u WHERE user_id = {id}
```

The subquery would be:

```
SELECT c.type, c.value, c.privacy_rule FROM users_contact c WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id
```

But how do I integrate it in the main query to return the array of result rows?
Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, after some more filling about, here is the answer.
use json_build_object:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, 
ARRAY(SELECT like_id FROM users_likes l WHERE l.user_id = u.user_id) as likes, 
ARRAY(SELECT json_build_object("contact_id", c.contact_id, 
"value", c.value, "privacy",c.privacy) 
FROM users_contact c WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id) as contact 
FROM users_basic u WHERE user_id = {id}
```

This gives:

```
"first_name": "This",
"last_name": "Is Me",
"about": null,
"likes": [],
"city": null,
"contact": [
  {
    "contact_id": 1,
    "value": "bbla",
    "privacy": 2,
    "type": "Phone"
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 3,
    "value": "blabla",
    "privacy": 2,
    "type": "Company Email"
  },
  {
    "contact_id": 4,
    "value": "blablabla",
    "privacy": 2,
    "type": "Telegram Id"
  }
]
```

Hope it helps someone